# Unwanted syntax changes to FxCop file

Tags: c#, vb.net, fxcop

We use FxCop on our project. All of our code is in C#.

When some developers make FxCop changes (e.g. remove suppressions) via the FxCop UI, many unwanted changes are made to the FxCop file. For other developers, this does not happen, even though we are on the same version of FxCop (v10.0.30319.1).

This is an example of a portion of the file before making changes (this portion is unrelated to the changes we wanted to make):

```
<Member Name="#Bar`1(!!0,!!0)">
  <Messages>
    <Message Id="Bar" TypeName="IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly" Category="Microsoft.Naming" CheckId="CA1709" Status="Excluded" >
      <Issue Name="Member">
        <Item>Bar</Item>
        <Item>Foo.Bar&lt;T&gt;(T, T)'</Item>
        <Item>Bar</Item>
      </Issue>
    </Message>
  </Messages>
</Member>
<Member Name="#Bar(System.Int32,System.Int32)">
  <Messages>
    <Message Id="Bar" TypeName="IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly" Category="Microsoft.Naming" CheckId="CA1709" Status="Excluded" >
      <Issue Name="Member">
        <Item>Bar</Item>
        <Item>Foo.Bar(int, int)'</Item>
        <Item>Bar</Item>
      </Issue>
    </Message>
  </Messages>
</Member>
```

Afterwards, the same section looks like this:

```
<Member Name="#Bar`1(!!0,!!0)">
  <Messages>
    <Message Id="Bar" TypeName="IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly" Category="Microsoft.Naming" CheckId="CA1709" Status="Excluded" >
      <Issue Name="Member">
        <Item>Bar</Item>
        <Item>Foo.Bar(Of T)(T, T)'</Item>
        <Item>Bar</Item>
      </Issue>
    </Message>
  </Messages>
</Member>
<Member Name="#Bar(System.Int32,System.Int32)">
  <Messages>
    <Message Id="Bar" TypeName="IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly" Category="Microsoft.Naming" CheckId="CA1709" Status="Excluded" >
      <Issue Name="Member">
        <Item>Bar</Item>
        <Item>Foo.Bar(Integer, Integer)'</Item>
        <Item>Bar</Item>
      </Issue>
    </Message>
  </Messages>
</Member>
```

So it looks like C# syntax is being changed to VB.NET syntax throughout (e.g. `<T>` becomes `(Of T)`, `int` becomes `Integer`).

The number of changes makes it almost impossible to see what changes were actually made when looking at the diff.

This problem has only recently started - things used to work OK. We've looked through the settings and found nothing we could change, tried re-installing, Googled aplenty... does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Which version of FxCop?  How are the developers modifying the file (via the FxCop UI or some other means)?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu I've edited my question. (Although it is not the latest version, we didn't use to have this problem...)